# Извлечение docker образа

Tags: docker

Пытаюсь извлечь резервную копию данных с сайта cropio из Docker. Вот инструкция.
PostgreSQL (включая Postgis) и Redis необходимы для запуска резервного копирования.
Скрипт для создания таблиц в БД —cropio_api_structure.sql
Вытащите образ из Docker Hub docker pull cropio/cropio-backupper

Запуск

Пример команды запуска контейнера (необходимо указать логины и пароли в переменных)

```
docker run -e "REDIS_HOST=" -e 
"CROPIO_LOGIN=" -e 
"CROPIO_PASSWORD=" \
-e "DB_NAME=" -e "DB_PORT=" -e 
"DB_USERNAME=" -e  
"DB_PASSWORD=" -e "DB_HOST=" \
-e "DOWNLOAD_SLEEP=10"
--restart=always cropio/cropio- 
backupper
```

(https://github.com/cropio/cropio-backupper)
Не могли бы объяснить новичку как это сделать? Работаю на windows